# Stable under finitely many set operations

Tags: probability-theory

In Williams' Probability with Martingales I encountered this statement :

"an algebra on $S$ is a family of subsets of $S$ stable under finitely many set operations"

Why does he insist on "finitely many"? what does happen if not "finitely"?

He also says : "Although not all sets are measurable, it is always the case for probability theory that enough sets are measurable"?

I don't understand this statement as well. Is it related to the first one too?

Comment: It means "closed" under finite many union or intersection. See e.g [Stable under Intersection](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Stable_under_Intersection).

Comment: There are [Non-measurable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set): quite "exotic" ones. Their existence is proved through the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I was asking, why "finite"

Comment: Maybe it's in distinction to a "sigma algeba," which is closed under *countable* unions or intersections (and complement).